# how to bind values INSERT INTO mysql perl

Tags: mysql, perl, bind

I've got the code below that works but I need to know how to bind them for security. If I just replace $new_row with ? and put it in execute I get an error. Thanks for your help.

```
foreach my $field (@account_field_order) {
$new_row .= "'" . param($field) . "', ";
}#foreach
$new_row .= "'$status'";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $MYSQLuserid, $MYSQLpassword ) 
          or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq(INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($new_row) )) or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: You need one question mark `?` for each field.

Comment: See TLP's answer on placeholders. Another reason to use placeholders: you can run prepared statements that only need to be parsed and compiled once by the DB manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use placeholders, and *never* interpolate variables in strings. You should probably use [taint mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode) and de-taint your `param` values before using them, if safety is important to you. Documentation on placeholders [here](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values).

Try something like:

```
my @values = map param($_), @account_field_order; # add values to array
push @values, $status;                  # for simplicity
$new_row = join ", ", ("?") x @values;  # add ? for each value

... # basically same code as before, except the execute statement:

$sth->execute(@values);      # arguments given will be inserted at placeholders
```

Comment: ok.. I used your code and I get this error..
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 at account.cgi line 745.

Comment: `my @values = map param($_), @account_field_order; 
    push @values, $status;
    my $new_row = join ", ", ("?") x @values; 
    my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $MYSQLuserid, $MYSQLpassword ) 
              or die $DBI::errstr;
     
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq(INSERT INTO $table VALUES       ($new_row)     )) or die $DBI::errstr;
 $sth->execute(@values) or die $DBI::errstr;`

Comment: @ta Well, the best I can do is repeat what the error says to you. You have a sync error somewhere. Try and find it. Oh, by the way, you are using `use strict; use warnings;`, right? If not, I suggest you do.

Answer (score 0):

If your values were in a hash, there's [the insert_hash example in the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#prepare_cached) (under prepare_cached). Adjust as appropriate if not using an array.