# bind values INSERT INTO mysql perl

Tags: mysql, perl, bind

Novice here. Just trying to bind values to eliminate sql injections. I've got the code below but I get this error...
called with 1 bind variables when 47 are needed at my.cgi line 803.
and output looks like..

```
$new_row='53616c7465645f5fd8b88f6a16704f8ebc0a2002dfg45633617bbb0446fa', 'test12', 'user', '2012-03-06', 'xcvb', 'xb', 'xcvbb', 'xcvbb', 'UT', 'US', '4566', '4564564566', 'todd@my.com', 'vbn', '', '200', 'Monthly', 'eBook', 'WebStore', '9.95', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'http://my.com', 'my.com', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2012-03-06', '30-Day-Trial'
$questionmarks=?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
```

I've tried it with/without quotes and commas. Any ideas appreciated.

```
foreach my $field (@account_field_order) {
$new_row .= "'" . param($field) . "', ";
$questionmarks .="?, ";
}#foreach
$new_row .= "'$status'";
$questionmarks .= "? ";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $MYSQLuserid, $MYSQLpassword ) 
          or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq(INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($questionmarks) )) 
or  die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->execute(qq($new_row)) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to supply a *list* of arguments, one for each questionmark, not a single scalar argument that contains the strings of the arguments. When I [answered your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570111/725418) before, I told you to do:

```
my @values = map param($_), @account_field_order; # add values to array
push @values, $status;                  # for simplicity
$new_row = join ", ", ("?") x @values;  # add ? for each value

... # basically same code as before, except the execute statement:

$sth->execute(@values);      # arguments given will be inserted at placeholders
```

Where `$new_row` is your placeholder string, not your argument list. *Not:*

```
$new_row .= "'" . param($field) . "', ";
...
$new_row .= "'$status'";
$sth->execute(qq($new_row)) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Because `$new_row` counts as one argument, since it is a scalar. You need an array or list of the same length as the number of questionmarks.

Comment: I used your code and got an error like 'values don't match column count' because it was only executing 22 params/values. The table has 47 fields/columns. BUT, it gave me the idea for the above code which seems to be closer.

Comment: Perhaps it is an SQL error. It is hard to tell, since you do not give me much information.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets fix the first statements:

```
@new_row=('53616c7465645f5fd8b88f6a16704f8ebc0a2002dfg45633617bbb0446fa', 'test12', 'user', '2012-03-06', 'xcvb', 'xb', 'xcvbb', 'xcvbb', 'UT', 'US', '4566', '4564564566', 'todd@my.com', 'vbn', '', '200', 'Monthly', 'eBook', 'WebStore', '9.95', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'http://my.com', 'my.com', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2012-03-06', '30-Day-Trial');
$questionmarks="?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?";
```

These will create an array of values and a single string with all the ?s.

Then in the execute statement:

```
$sth->execute(@new_row) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

which will pass in your array of values into the execute line, rather than a single argument like you were doing before.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense but when I modified it I get this error... called with 2 bind variables when 0 are needed at account.cgi line 752.

Comment: `foreach my $field (@account_field_order) {`
 `$new_row .= "'" . param($field) . "', ";`
 `$questionmarks .="?, ";`
 `}#foreach`
`@new_row=$new_row;`
`push (@new_row, "'$status'");`
`$questionmarks .= "? ";`
`my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq(INSERT INTO $table VALUES "$questionmarks" )) or die $DBI::errstr;`
`$sth->execute(@new_row) or die $DBI::errstr;`

Comment: Ok. Figured it out.. `foreach my $field (@account_field_order) {
 push (@new_row, "'param($field)', ");
 $questionmarks .="?, ";
 }#foreach

push (@new_row,  "'$status'");
$questionmarks .= "? ";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database";
  my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $MYSQLuserid, $MYSQLpassword ) 
              or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq(INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($questionmarks) )) or die $DBI::errstr;
 $sth->execute(@new_row) or die $DBI::errstr;`