# transform csv file to mysql insert statement

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to generate MySQL file from CSV data

```
90927744|1356976814398|0|1356976815339|18563182571|18563182571|18568753009|18563574221
```

is there is a way that I could use awk or sed to generate mysql insert statement as follows

```
insert into table (id,value,status,starttime,endtime,number,phone,number) values (90927744,1356976814398,0,1356976815339,18563182571,18563182571,18568753009,18563574221);
```

Thank you

Comment: using `awk` with `field separator` as `|` you can get all the fields separately. Then you need to relate `1st field` to `id`, `2nd field` to `value`, and so on....

Comment: I tried to cat the file and pipe it to awk to add the "insert syntax, then the values between (), but I stumbled upon getting the syntax right

Comment: I have added an answer with examples...hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract a particular field from your input....

```
$echo "90927744|1356976814398|0|1356976815339|18563182571|18563182571|18568753009|18563574221" |  awk -F "|" '{print $4}'
1356976815339
```

If you have one line in `a.txt` (see the script below for multiple lines in the input file)

```
$cat a.txt | awk -F "|" '{print $4}'
```

So to output the query you want--

```
$cat a.txt | awk -F "|" '{printf("insert into table (id,value,status,starttime,endtime,number,phone,number) values (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d) \n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)}'
```

If your file has multiple lines, then use the following script (or adapt this to your needs)

```
while read line           
do           
     echo "$line" | awk -F "|" ........
done < a.txt
```

Comment: I would suggest to use bound values instead of explicitly define the values. It makes slower if a lot of such lines are inserted. See topic about `bind values` in [this related SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587743/bind-values-insert-into-mysql-perl).

Answer (score 1):

Just to refine the above written AWK statement, instead of while loop we can use

```
awk -F "|" '{printf("insert into table (id,value,status,starttime,endtime,number,phone,number) values (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d) \n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)}' a.txt >> result.txt
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sql="insert into table (id,value,status,starttime,endtime,number,phone,number) values"
sed 'y/|/,/;s/.*/'"$sql"' (&);/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use csvkit, see [How to let csvkit/csvsql generate insert statements for csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449406/how-to-let-csvkit-csvsql-generate-insert-statements-for-csv-file)

The statements will be for sqlite, the database engine behind csvkit, but conversion should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question already is pretty old, someone might fall over it...

so another way of doing this is using standard ways for reading CSV files with [LOAD DATA syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) which allows to use CSV files to read data and inserting it into a table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

which takes the data from the CSV file and splits the valies on the | symbol.

Comment: FWIW, once loaded, you can then use mysqldump to create a .sql file. Not quite the same as generating inserts though.