# How to let csvkit/csvsql generate insert statements for csv file?

Tags: sql, csv, terminal, csvkit

I want to generate sql insert statements for some csv file.

I can do this using a one-liner awk script such as:

```
awk -F "\t" '{printf("INSERT INTO T_COMMON_ENUM_VALUE (id,name,category_id) values (%s, '\''%s'\'', %s, %s);\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}'
```

But this still requires some effort. csvsql inside csvkit seems to generate insert statements automatically. I checked the [documentation](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/scripts/csvsql.html) and used the following command but it doesn't generate insert statements.

```
$ cat data02.csv
db_enumvalue_id db_enumvalue_name       db_enumcategory_id
800     şirin   9

$ csvsql data02.csv
CREATE TABLE data02 (
        db_enumvalue_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        db_enumvalue_name VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
        db_enumcategory_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

It generates the create table statements. But the documentation says:

```
Generate SQL statements for a CSV file or execute those statements directly on a database.
```

What should I do to get the insert sql statements using csvkit?

Comment: the documentation says to specify the database and add a --insert argument like so: --insert --db postgresql:///test --insert examples/*.csv However I find the behavior is equivalent to the above, where the table is created but the rows are not inserted.

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/blob/master/csvkit/utilities/csvsql.py), it will only directly execute insert statements, not output them.

Comment: @Blorgbeard nonetheless, it doesn't seem to execute them. When I look at the database contents the table is there but there are no rows (even though there are in the csv).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an entirely data-driven way.  Slightly goofy, but it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##
## ensure script stops on errors
set -eu
set -o pipefail

##
## load your data into a SQLite DB
csvsql test.csv --db=sqlite:///test.db --insert

##
## let SQLite generate the inserts
echo ".dump test" | sqlite3 test.db
```

Run that and you get something like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    month VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    market FLOAT NOT NULL,
    acme FLOAT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(1,'1/86',-0.061134,0.03016);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(2,'2/86',0.00822,-0.165457);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(3,'3/86',-0.007381,0.080137);
...
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(60,'12/90',-0.026401,-0.190834);
COMMIT;
```

Capture that in a file and you're golden.  Could also be wrapped in a Python subprocess call, or piped into a database command line client, if you want to automate the insert phase as well.

If you're inserting to an existing table, this approach works for a DBMS like MySQL that does implicit type conversions, since CSV can't define data types for fields past strings vs. numbers. For a more strict DBMS like Postgres, you would need to edit the data types in the script file.

Comment: Hitting a problem when I round-trip through sqlite3, getting 0.29999999999999998889 instead of 0.3 (lack of DECIMAL type, binary floating point issues introduced when value round-trip through sqlite3).

Answer (score 1):

looking at documentation, I guess someting like that:

if destination table T_COMMON_ENUM_VALUE already exists:

```
$ csvsql --tables T_COMMON_ENUM_VALUE --insert --no-create data02.csv
```

if destination table T_COMMON_ENUM_VALUE does not exists:

```
$ csvsql --tables T_COMMON_ENUM_VALUE --insert data02.csv
```

this should only output the script, if you want the statements executed to your db, you need to add `--db CONNECTION_STRING`, for example:

```
$ csvsql --db mssql://user:pass@host:port/database --tables T_COMMON_ENUM_VALUE --insert data02.csv
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Does not work for me , It says "The --insert option is only valid when either --db or --query is specified."

Comment: so use the last

Comment: I do not wish to run the commands. I googled some more and it seems not feasible using csvkit

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no straightforward solution to generate insert or delete SQL script using csvsql; at least I could not find one myself when I needed it desperately. However, the `--query` option comes to our rescue by allowing us to prepare such statements ourselves. Of course, it needs a little bit of effort, but it pays off very well.

Here is an example. I have a csv file (called test2.csv). This is how I am able to generate insert statements for all rows in the csv file.

```
csvsql  --query "SELECT 'insert into test2  values (''' ||    
trim(ifnull(my_table.survived, 'null123')) ||''' ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.RECORD_TYPE, 'null123')) ||''' ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.BASE_HIN, 'null123')) ||''' ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.SUFFIX, 'null123')) ||''',''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.name, 'null123')) ||''' ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.ADDRESS_1, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.ADDRESS_2, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.CITY, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.STATE, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.PRIMARY_ZIP, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.COUNTRY, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.TELEPHONE, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.CLASS_OF_TRADE, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.DEA, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.DATE_HIN_ASSIGNED, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.DATE_LAST_EDITED, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.STATUS, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.VERIFIED, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.LAST_ACTION_CODE, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.REASON_CODE, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.REFERBACK_CODE, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.SUBSET, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.UPIN, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.SPECIALTY, 'null123')) ||'''  ,''' ||     
trim(ifnull(my_table.FAX, 'null123')) ||''' )'FROM test2 as my_table WHERE survived='0'" test2.csv > insert.sql
```

Make sure that this is one single line because csvsql does not like broken lines.

Also, once the `insert.sql` is prepared, you need to remove the header line, remove double quotes (from all the rows) and also find and replace `= 'null123'` with `is null`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Ahmed-M-Salah/CsvToSql

A C# project.  Updated fork of a prior project 5-7 years ago.